# What is the process for brewing egg coffee?

Tags: brewing-process, egg-coffee

There was recently a question about the [history of brewing coffee with eggs](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1509/what-is-the-background-of-brewing-coffee-with-eggs), but what is the actual process involved?

Are there different receipies from different cultures? If so, what are they?

Comment: Still looks a bit like a duplicate to me, but maybe I just worded my question a bit too fuzzily. But at least your answer fits a bit better here.

Comment: @ChristianRau That's what I thought too, but there were some comments on my answer that suggested that you weren't looking for receipies. If you want to tweak your quesiton, I'll un-delete my answer and remove this one (I think it makes sense to keep them all in the same place too).

Comment: Hmm, not entirely sure, too. I also admit that I thought your answer didn't really fit over there. I'm not really looking for exact recipes that much. I guess I'd be fine with the situation for now and see how this stuff develops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to give this a shot and made up a recipe myself:

I started out by simply making a press pot of coffee:

[image: french press]

then, after letting the coffee cool and steep for a few minutes, mixed up and [tempered](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/how-do-i-temper-an-egg) two eggs (shell and all) by spooning in some of the coffee and grounds:

[image: tempering the eggs]

This part starts to look pretty nasty, but persevere:

[image: tempered eggs]

Whip the eggs into an emulsion (or close to it; this will be much easier with a whisk), and pour them into the press pot. Once you're done you should have an eggy crema on top (I think I needed one or two more eggs for the entire press pot):

[image: egg coffee]

As far as I can tell, it just tastes like coffee (the egg is hardly noticeable, and just tones down the flavor a bit like cream or milk). Using one or two more eggs (for a full pot like this) would probably have helped. Also, make sure you let the coffee cool enough before tempering your eggs, or you'll just wind up with scrambled egg floating in coffee despite the fact that you tempered it.

Comment: This is amazing! But wouldn't there be a risk of salmonella from the raw eggs?

Comment: Probably; I've been making eggnog and the like with raw eggs for years and never had a problem though. I just take my chances. You could probably reheat the coffee after it's made, or turn it into an Irish coffee to kill anything that was in the eggs. Just a guess though; the usual disclaimers (about me not being a doctor or food scientist) apply :)

Comment: Looks like melted chocolate... ***YUM!***

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is this website on [Norwegian Egg Coffee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89GL4.jpg). It is a a recipe on egg coffee, Norwegian style! Sadly, I am not a chef, but it only has 4 steps:

Ingredients:

- 80 g coarsely ground coffee (roughly 200 mL)
- 1 egg
- 100 mL cold water
- 2.5 L boiling water
- 250 mL cold water

> Mix coffee with an egg and 100 mL cold water to a thick paste.

You simply mix your coffee with an egg plus 100 ml/ a fifth of a pint of cold water with something like a spoon until it becomes a thick paste. It should get harder as the paste thickens along the way.

> Add this mixture to the boiling water (2.5 L in a pot on the stove over a fire to be exact), stir carefully and leave to boil for 2-3 min.

Put the paste in boiling water that is placed in a metal pot over a fire on a stove. Stir carefully then leave the mixture to boil for 2 to 3 minutes. There will be a difference in the end product depending on how much you stirred it:
[image]

> Difference between much (left) and little (right) stirring as the coffee boils as seen from the precipitate at the bottom of a glass of egg coffee. **PythonMaster's Note**: This is the caption for the picture above.

The next step is actually the next step in the recipe, not a caption:

> Remove pot from stove and add the remaining cold water

Clearly, remove your pot from the stove and then add remaining 250 ml of cold water into the pot. Pretty self-explanatory.

> Let the grounds settle for a couple of minutes, skim off any floating particles, filter through a fine meshed sieve, a cheese cloth or filter paper and serve.

Place the mixture somewhere and let the grounds settle for a couple minutes (You probably want to put this in a cup or container). As it settles, use a spoon to remove any floating particles in the mixture. Then after it settles, put the mixture through some type of sieve (please have container underneath or you will have a really delicious mess to clean up) and finally... ***DRINK AND SERVE!***

The following images are suppose to go with the steps of this recipe:[image]

I hope this helps you!